# Is commenting on incorrect answer the proper way to point out it's wrong?

Tags: discussion, comments, wrong-answers

From previous encounters with incorrect answers, I got the impression that proper "etiquette" included

- down-voting it
- providing a correct answer, if one doesn't already exist, or upvoting the correct answer if it does
- leaving a comment on the incorrect answer explaining why it is incorrect

Previous discussions I've almost universally seemed to suggest that last point is the way to highlight the mistake.  I'm now wondering about the last bullet for two reasons:

1. I've seen it mentioned in a number of meta-discussions that comments are "second-class citizens" and that they are transient in some way
2. My own comment(s) pointing out how an accepted answer was technically incorrect were recently deleted (not sure through which mechanism)

What then is the correct method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I mostly let downvotes speak for themselves, except under these circumstances:

- the answer has already been (wrongly) upvoted or is otherwise very prominent and is promoting wrong facts too prominently
- the answer isn't completely wrong and has some good points, but has some minor issues that need addressing (also consider editing it in this case)
- the answer is technically correct, but may fail under certain circumstances (which may or may not apply specifically in the question's case) or is otherwise sub-optimal in a way that potential users should know about

In other circumstances, where the answer is just blatantly wrong and it's already being downvoted, and the correct answer is already provided, I mostly do not bother to comment. That just seems like piling on.

Comment: *Consider* editing, don't jump to editing all the time. For example, fixing a non-obvious typo in the code is an invalid edit.

Comment: the case that got me to ask the question, the wrong answer was posted *after* two not-wrong answers, and it was upvoted *and* acepted putting it first, as far as content, the only correct part of it was a restatement of what the other two answers already said. What it added of its own was incorrect, based on incorrect assumptions, and "proved" by a degenerate "test case" (trivial and non-representative of real life). But of course all that makes it look "more" credible.  I'm particularly confused by disappeared comment explaining what was wrong in the answer though.

Comment: @Asya Sounds exactly like a case for a comment. If you want to know details about why your comment was removed, I'd suggest you open a new question here on Meta with a link to the disputed answer; mods might be able to provide some insight.

Comment: I didn't realize "why was my comment removed" was a valid "meta" question - at least when it applies to a specific comment...

Comment: @Asya Let's say that moderators probably wouldn't be happy about answering such quibbles all day long, but it's really the only avenue of communication for such topics there is. So, if you're *really* interested to get an answer to this... :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to commenting, you can also ask the asker to review the answers, and hope they'll mark the correct one as accepted.

See more in [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286634/1269037).