# What should I do if an answer is just plain wrong?

Tags: support, answers, wrong-answers

I have stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23863370/417501) which is just plain wrong. I left a comment below it to indicate why the answer is incorrect and potentially destructive. Is there any other measure I should take? Is flagging the answer correct behavior in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to flag it. If it's wrong, downvote it and (as you have) leave a comment explaining what the problem is. This is not something that moderators will take any action on.

Comment: There needs to be a better way to handle this. People will see the answer marked as accepted and there is no clear way to make visible that the content is not correct.

Comment: @FUZxxl There is: leaving a comment. If people agree with you, your comment will be upvoted and the answer downvoted. I understand your frustration (having been in the same situation) but that's the way it is.

Comment: @Stijn I doubt that many people will review a question with an answer that has been marked as accepted. I fear that my comment will not be read by those who read the answer.

Comment: Unless you have a particularly great idea, this is as good as it gets @FUZxxl. The tick mark was only ever meant to indicate helpfulness as judged by the OP. It is not a sign of correctness.

Comment: @Bart I fear that others might misunderstand that. Is it acceptable to edit the answer to indicate its falsehood?

Comment: No, it is not. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: People *do* notice when the accepted answer is heavily downvoted. At least, it motivates them to read the second-listed answer, the one the community has "accepted" by upvotes. @fuz

Answer (score 3):

I've also downvoted plain wrong answers, and commented on why they were wrong, but if the answer is popular and at the top of the list (or worse, accepted), it can take *ages* for a better answer to come up. That is, if the question isn't already [closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late).

Editing the answer to point out that it is no longer accurate may be morally right, but as far as I've seen, is against SO policies because it changes the overall meaning of the answer significantly. However, see [this answer on historically popular but wrong answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers/255470#255470), which suggests it may be okay to edit the wrong answer and point to a correct one.

Flagging it for moderator attention may again feel right but moderators aren't tasked with evaluating technical accuracy.

The only semi-effective measure I've found was to leave a comment on the question and ask the OP to revise the answers. You can hope they'll accept a correct one. In my experience, about half the time this was the case, while in the other half the OP has moved on and stopped having enough current knowledge, interest or time to review the answers, or was no longer active on the site.

I'm afraid this is the best we have. So do leave a comment on the question, and hope the asker will have a second look!

Answer (score 1):

Judging the technical correctness of an answer is not a job for moderators, but for subject matter experts.

You can often get the attention of other subject matter experts (who will let you know if you missed something, or else add their votes to yours) in a relevant chatroom.